# Retrieve Bluetooth address on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, mac-address

I try to retrieve the Bluetooth (Network) adress on the iPhone within an App but i couldn't find a way how to do that :( 
Does someone has an idea or hint? That would be great  because i stuck for a long time...

Cheers, Lars

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the hardware address calling getifaddrs().  See http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/getifaddrs.3.html .

Comment: Thanks for the tip! 
I will try to make it work.
Meanwhile, any other ideas to retrieve it?

Thanks in advance! Lars

Comment: I'm fairly certain that this is the only way you can (reliably) do it.